# How to schedule another instance of a worker with the same unique name when the worker has finished, using WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a task that needs to run once at the end of every month approximately at 00:00.
I have implemented it in the following way:

```
fun schedule(existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy) {
  val scheduleTimeMillis = getMonthEnd()
  val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MonthlyWorker>()
    .setInitialDelay(scheduleTimeMillis - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build()
  val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

  workManager.enqueueUniqueWork("MonthlyWorker", existingWorkPolicy, work)
}
```

I run `schedule(ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE)` at boot and on TIME_SET (only one of it should exist)

and `schedule(ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND)` in `doWork()` of MonthlyWorker. (scheduling for the next month before the current work is finished)

This results in the MonthlyWorker moving to BLOCKED state after executing

What is the correct way to do this?